# How come my Edit Reply function isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I have an edit function for the forum project that I am doing, but whenever I click on it, I was given an error.
[image]

[image]

The error seems to be in my editReply.ejs file, which currently has these code:

```
    <!-- boilerplate.ejs set up the general layout for this ejs file. -->
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate')%>
<!-- The form goes submit a PUT requests on localhost:3000/threads/:id/replies/:replyId, which overrides POST request.  
    The form's inputs have values equal to reply object's current replyContent.  -->
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="text-center">Edit Reply</h1>
  <div class="col-6 offset-3">
    <form
      action="/threads/<%=thread._id%>/replies/<%=reply._id%>?_method=PUT"
      method="POST"
      novalidate
      class="validated-form"
    >
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label" for="replyContent">Content</label>
          <textarea
            class="form-control"
            rows="5"
            cols="50"
            id="replyContent"
            name="thread[replyContent]"
            required
          >
<%=reply.replyContent%></textarea
          >
          <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <button class="btn btn-success">Update Reply</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My app.js file has the following codes:

```
    // If there's an error, catchAsync will catch the error and the use method will be invoked.  
// Edit the reply, localhost:3000/threads/:id/replies/:replyId/edit.  :id is the thread's ID, :replyId is reply's ID.  
// Find the thread and reply by the ID.  
// Pass the thread and reply object into editReply.ejs of threads folder.  
app.get('/threads/:id/replies/:replyId/edit', catchAsync(async(req, res) => {
    const thread = await Reply.findById(req.params.id);
    const reply = await Reply.findById(req.params.replyId);
    res.render('threads/editReply', { thread, reply });
}));

// If there's an error, catchAsync will catch the error and the use method will be invoked.  
// validateReply is a middleware function that validates the thread schema.  
// If I submit the form on localhost:3000/threads/:id/replies/:replyId/edit, 
// a put request will be sent to localhost:3000/threads/:id/replies/:replyId.  
// The object with the corresponding reviewId will be removed from the current thread's replies array property.  
// The reply itself will be updated, then rejoin the replies array of the current thread.  
// Redirect to localhost:3000/threads/:id after a form is submitted.  
app.put('/threads/:id/replies/:replyId', validateReply, catchAsync(async(req, res) => {
    const { id, replyId } = req.params;
    const thread = await Thread.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $pull: { replies: replyId }});
    const reply = await Reply.findByIdAndUpdate(replyId, {...req.body.thread});
    reply.replyLastEditTime = new Date();
    thread.replies.push(reply);
    await reply.save();
    await thread.save();
    res.redirect(`/threads/${id}`)
}));
```

Please let me know why I am encountering that error.

Comment: Either `thread` or `reply` is null in your `app.get` handler.  You'll need to add some logging to figure out which one it is.